# Variable assignment outside class definition

Tags: c++

I'm fairly inexperienced with C++ and I'm trying to understand what this code does.

---

```
template <typename T>
class System : public BaseSystem
{
[..]
private:
static SystemType sysType;
};
```

Outside the class definition there is something like this:

```
template <typename T>
SystemType System<T>::sysType= IDGen<BaseSystem>::GenerateNextID();
```

Is this setting the `sysType` field in the `System` class to a new ID? But since the `sysType` field is `private` how is it able to access it? Also, why is the type included before the assignment?

If I wanted to change a field I would do something like `field = newvalue;` however this `Foo field = newvalue;` seems like it's creating a new field of type `Foo` and then assigning it.

Can anyone explain what is that line of code doing?

Comment: no, it's not an assignment. It's the initialization of the static member variable. Static member variables have to be defined outside the class declaration.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant initialization **and definition**.

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah, that's why I wrote "have to be defined".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: It's just that your comment makes definition and initialization seem to be synonymous, or at least implying each other. Which it is not.

Comment: @Deduplicator sorry for that, I didn't mean to imply that they are related…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not an "assignment". It is the *definition* of the static data member `sysType` of your class. In your case the syntax contains quite a bit of template-related stuff, but the immediate matter in question has nothing to do with templates at all. A minimalistic example of the same thing might look as follows

```
class SomeClass { 
  ...
  static int i; // declaration of `SomeClass::i`
  ...
};

int SomeClass::i = 42; // definition of `SomeClass::i`
```

All static members of the class have to be *defined* somewhere (with some exceptions for constant integral members). What you have inside the class is a mere *declaration*.

So, one more time: every time you *declare* a static data member in your class, you will have to *define* it somewhere outside of the class, following the general One Definition Rule for data objects with external linkage, i.e. you have to define in your program once and only once.

In your case the definition includes an initializer. The `=` is a part of the initialization syntax. It has nothing to do with assignment.

The access protection does not come into play here at all. In this case you are not *accessing* a class member, you are *defining* it. Just like you *define* private member functions outside of the class, you *define* private static members outside of the class.